# Language recomendation for new project, Python or Scala

Tags: python, apache-flex, scala, xml-rpc

I'm 8 years in Enterprice development in Java(JavaEE, ESB, Oracle atc). Now I would like to start my private project. Taking in accout my kind of "dissapoinment" with Java, and mainly that I have cca 3hours per day for private project, I have decided to make it in some more productive enviroment. Gui will be Flex to avoid browser related HTML/CSS etc issues. GUI will do xml-rpc calls to backend. And the backed is <...>

I have to mention that I have no experience with Scala or Python. Project can get quite large in functionality during development. Making a small prototype is not a help here cause possible language issues can be far away from simple prototype.

Type safety is not an issue for me. Nearly 80% of my code is always unit tested and code is mostly well layed out.

One way to think about is to startup with Python go get results quickly and if project will be accepted by target community it could be possibly rewriten to Scala for example. I'm not sure for now. Can you make some points to take in consideration?

Many Thanks

Comment: Both good choices, but you already know the Java ecosystem, the best choice *for you* is almost certainly Scala.  Better the VM you know...